# How to perform an operation with an undefined amount of <select>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in html:

```html
<select onchenge="action('account1')">
  <option value="1">op 1</option>
</select>
```

I need the function to also receive the selected value without using an id. (because I have an unlimited amount from the tag)
How can this be done?

This is my javascript code:

```js
function action(account) {
  const email = account
  const select = // value*
}
```

Comment: Where would the selected value come from? What's the function look like? What do you mean by "an unlimited amount from the tag"? BTW, your "onchange" is misspelled, but `addEventListener()` is really the way to go.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: isn't it just something like `e.target.selectedOptions`  in your action definition?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` listener to be a function, instead you put a string. It should be something like the below code. Hope this will help you.

```
export default function App() {
    ....
    function action(e, account) {
        ....
        const select = e.target.value;
    }
    return(
        ....
        <select onChange={(e) => action(e, "account1")}>
            <option value="1">op 1</option>
        </select>
        ....
    )
}
```